# How to incorporate webdriver object from conftest.py in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, inheritance, webdriver

I have a conftest.py which initializes the firefox instance and opens the page. But as soon as I want to use in my test_functional.py by inheriting that fixture. I get a webdriver=None error. I am not sure how to pass driver variable the values from conftest.py. Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

```py
#conftest.py
@pytest.fixture
def webdriver(request):
    from selenium import webdriver
    request.instance.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    request.instance.driver.get("http://localhost:8443/")
    request.addfinalizer(request.instance.driver.quit)`
```

test_functional.py looks like:

```py
# test_functional.py
import pytest
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("webdriver")
class TestFunction:
    def test_username(self, webdriver):
        self.driver = webdriver
        elem = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
        s = "pass"
        print(s)`
```

The error I am getting is:

```
self = <test_functional.TestHighchar object at 0x03E30590>, **webdriver = None**

    def test_series(self, webdriver):
        self.driver = webdriver
>       elem = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
E       NameError: name 'driver' is not defined

test_functional.py:13: NameError
========================== 1 failed in 19.95 seconds ==========================
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of a pytest fixture is *the return value of its constructor function*. Because your `webdriver` fixture constructor function returns nothing, your test function receives nothing.

Simply return the instantiated driver from your fixture constructor function and it will be passed to your test function:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def webdriver(request):
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    request.addfinalizer(driver.quit)
    return driver
```

---

**P.S.** The use of `@pytest.mark.usefixtures("webdriver")` is unnecessary. The fixture will be automatically constructed and provided to your test function because the `webdriver` argument matches the fixture name.